# EF FirstOrDefault creates reference to variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So im new to C# and all its ecosystem. I am following a tutorial right now where a record is being updated:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSetup(int id, SetupForUpdateDto setupForUpdateDto)
    {
        var statusFromRepo = await this.setupRepository.GetValue(id);

        statusFromRepo.Name = setupForUpdateDto.Name;

        if (await this.setupRepository.saveAll())
        {
            return NoContent();
        }

        throw new Exception($"Updating User with Id: {id} failed on save");
    }
```

i dont understand why is the data to the db saved if the variable

```
statusFromRepo.Name = setupForUpdateDto.Name;
```

is updated and then

```
await this.setupRepository.saveAll()
```

is there somehow a reference btw the `statusFromRepo` variable and the `setupRepository`?

Comment: You should read about [Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). In short, `statusFromRepo` refers to _the same object_ that `setupRepository` has access to. Variables of _reference_ types are simply a reference to the actual objects. The object doesn't get copied (by default); what gets copied is the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on what the setupRepository does. Quite often, a repository (or the DbContext that the repository uses) remembers the original data that it fetched as well as a copy. This makes it possible to make changes without saving intermediate results.

Let's Change / Add / Delete a Customer from the repository, and see what happens.

Change existing Customer:

```
var customer = repository.FetchCustomerWithId(10);
// the original unchanged customer object is in the repository
// a copy of this object is also in the repository
// the copy equals the original
// I have a reference to this copy.

customer.Address = textBoxAddress.Text;
// the repository still has the original unchanged object
// my reference changed the copy object
// the copy is not equal to the original anymore.
```

Add new Customer

```
Customer customerToAdd = new Customer() {...};
repository.AddCustomer(customerToAdd);
// I have a new customer object
// the repository has a reference to this object
// the repository has no original: so it knows it is added
// alternative: the respository remembers that is was added.
```

Delete existing Customer

```
Customer customerToDelete = repository.FetchCustomerWithId(20);
// repository has original fetched object
// repository has copy equal to original object
// I have reference to the copy.

 repository.DeleteCustomer(customerToDelete);
 // I still have reference to the customer, I can change it if I want
 // the repository still has the original fetched customer object
 // the repository has deleted its copied Customer object
 // alternative: repository has remembered that this object is deleted.

 customerToDelete.Address = ...
 // The repository has deleted the copy, but I had still a reference,
 // so the copied Customer still exists, but the Repository does not know 
 // about the changed address.
```

Now what happens if you call SaveAll:

```
repository.SaveAll();
```

The repository checks which items were added: Find the copy objects with a NULL original: Add the object to the database

The repository checks which items were deleted: find the fetched objects that have a null copy object: Remove the object from the database

The repository checks all properties for each fetched objects that has a non-null copy: update the changed properties.

Alternative: for every object the repository remembers whether it was Added / Removed / Fetched. Only for the fetched data it has to check which properties need to be updated.

If the repository uses entity framework, then `DbContext.ChangeTracker` is the object that detects changes: which objects are Added / Removed / Changed.

See [DbChangeTracker class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)